# I don't want circles in my line Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new at using HighCharts in javascript. I'm doing a line chart, but the chart put me some circles in the graphics by default like this:

[image: chart]
<sub>(source: [misoproject.com](http://misoproject.com/images/examples/highchart.gif))</sub>

But i don't want that, i want to quit those circles.
What can i do to quit those circles in my graphic?

Comment: Did you look at highcharts documentation?

Comment: Yes, but i'm really baaaad at english, i'm a begginer programmer from Latin America

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this configuration option:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    marker: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
}
```

to the root of your chart configuration.